# Which is the preferable way to add a floating button in an Angular (5) application?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-routing, angular-components, angular-module

I'm building an application in **Angular 5** with 3 main screens which we can navigate using tabs. I used Angular routing for switching between these 3 views and added separate components for each of these 3. Now I want to add a floating button at the bottom of the screen which on click opens a new screen with a close button.
**NOTE:** This button should be common across the application and even if the screens change, I should not see this button vanishing and reappear after each screen load.

The main doubt here is what's the preferable way to add the button?

1. Floating button **Module**
2. Floating button **Template**
3. Any other one?

I'm good with creating the front-end for this and the further operations that happen inside that. But wanted to know the best (suggested) practice to add that button functionality.

Also please explain the basic skeleton and the reason why you suggest that way.

Thanks

Comment: Just create a floating button component, and add it to the HTML file that contains your router outlet

Answer (score 3):

A floating button is just a button with some CSS applied to it. You do not need any special Angular concepts in order to implement it.

Since your requirement was that the button is persistent across all screens, even when the Angular route changes, it means you want this button placed next to the top-most `<router-outlet>` you have in the application, which is usually in the `AppComponent`'s template (but could vary depending on your structure).

So just put the button there and style it.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <button class="float" (click)="onFloatClick()">Icon</button>
  `,
  styles: `
    .float {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 1rem;
      right: 1rem;
      width: 1.5em;
      height: 1.5em;
    }
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  public onFloatClick () {
    // do your magic
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way that I can do something like this - $('.float').on('click', (function(){dosomething})) in the component class rather than adding the (click)  in the button and implementing that method in the component?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, Renderer is the way to do the above one?

Comment: Why would you want to use your first example instead of the second one? The whole idea templates is to escape the first way of doing things.

Comment: If I do not want to touch the DOM and want to write all the click events at a place, wouldn't it be helpful if I write it separately rather than writing (click) / (focus) / (change) etc in a single line. That would be easier to write the template and event listeners independently. This way I can come back and write an extra event listener to the button without disturbing the template.. right?